# Vuejs getting data from local json

Tags: json, vue.js, vuejs2, vue-component, vue-props

I got some json data in a local file the file is .txt file and the data is not directly accessible so I just changed the file format to .json and after that, I tried to get clean data to loop through with the code below.

I'm getting the data via computed in this component but I want to set this clean data as a prop to a child component.

I want to create many child components with clean data.

Thank you very much in advance!

Code:

```
<script>
 export default {
  name: 'Dashboard',
  components : {
    'my-table': mytable,
    'my-search': search,
  },

  data: function() {
    return {
      casesDataList: [],

    };
  },

  computed:{
    ClearList: function(){
     var casesDataList = this.casesDataList.map(function (neo){
        return {ID: neo.Attributes[1].Value, Date: neo.FormattedValues[0].Value, Owner: neo.FormattedValues[1].Value};
      });
        return casesDataList;
    }
  },

  created: function(){
    this.getCasesData();
  },
  methods: {
    getCasesData() {
      fetch("Weather.json")
      .then(response => response.json())
      .then(data => (this.casesDataList = data.Entities));


    },
  }

};
</script>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can pass the computed as a prop to the child directly:

```
<child :propname="ClearList"></child>
```

In the child:

```js
export default {
    props: ['propname'],
    // ...
}
```

Comment: Thank you Dan! Is there any way in vuejs to make the data acceding simpler than I made?

Comment: You're welcome, it looks pretty good to me.  One improvement might be to use Vuex to manage state.  Then you could use a global getter instead of a computed and you wouldn't have to pass it everywhere as a prop since all components can easily access the store directly.